# How do I print from Emacs on Win32?

Tags: winapi, emacs, printing

I'm running Emacs 23.0.60.1, downloaded from [here](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html), on Windows XP, with a network printer configured as the default printer.

How do I setup Emacs to easily print buffer contents?

The [documentation](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32Util.html) of the patched Emacs version for Win32 mentions "quick and easy" printing, but the "Quick Print" menu entry does not appear and the regular entries ("Print Buffer", "Postscript Print Buffer") don't seem to do anything.

**EDIT:**
I'm having the same issue with the official windows build of Emacs 22.3. Therefore setup/troubleshooting instructions for any version would be appreciated.

**EDIT2:**
I went with the PrintFile solution presented by Joe Casadonte below, which works nicely. I'd still be interested in any ideas why the "proper" way is not working, though.

*(By the way, is this an appropriate SO question, being only marginally programming related?)*

Comment: I upgraded from Win32 Emacs 22 to Win32 Emacs 23, and found the same problem: the print-buffer menu no longer works as documented.

And, of course, I have totally failed to follow up on that.

Comment: re: appropriate SO question -- yes, I believe it is appropriate.  Emacs and VIM questions are asked and answered all the time here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the "proper" way, but I've been doing it this way for years and it works wonderfully.  I use [PrintFile](http://www.lerup.com/printfile/), a freeware print program (which can also be used stand-alone).  Then I have this in my .emacs:

```
(defun joc-make-fname-from-buffer-name (buffer-name-in)
  "Returns a valid filename from a given buffer name"
  (interactive "b")
  (save-match-data
    (let* ((start (string-match "[^ \*]" buffer-name-in))
           (end (string-match "[ \*]*$" buffer-name-in (match-end 0)))
           (rc (substring buffer-name-in start end)))
      ;; remove some special characters
      (while (string-match "[:]+" rc)
        (setq rc (replace-match "_" t t rc)))
      rc)))

(when is-win32
    (defun joc-print-buffer-or-region (prefix)
      "Prints buffer or region via PrintFile32.  If a prefix arg is set (via C-u) then
       the current region is printed, otherwise the current buffer is printed."

      (interactive "P")

      ;; ----- set the print directory, fname and args -----
      (let* ((print-dir (expand-file-name "~/emacs/print"))
             (print-fname (joc-make-fname-from-buffer-name (buffer-name)))
             (print-fullpath (concat print-dir "/" print-fname))
             (print-args "/delete")
             ;; ----- set rstart and rend to the current region -----
             (rstart (point-min)) (rend (point-max)))

        ;; ----- if prefix given, set them to region -----
        (if (and prefix)
            (if (and (point) (mark) (/= (point) (mark)))
                (progn (setq rstart (min (point) (mark)))
                       (setq rend (max (point) (mark))))
              (error "No region defined")))

        ;; ----- make the directory -----
        (if (not (file-directory-p print-dir))
            (make-directory print-dir))

        ;; ----- write buffer/region to a temp file, print it, delete directory -----
        (write-region rstart rend print-fullpath)
        (call-process "prfile32" nil t nil print-args print-fullpath)
        (delete-directory print-dir))))
```

I haven't looked at it in years cause it just works, so I'm sure it could be improved.

Comment: Works great on my XP; thanks for pointing to an excellent application! However -- how could I (a) add support to non-Latin characters (or UTF-8) and (b) Have linebreaks by _words_ and not _characters_? These may well be issues with PrintFile and not Emacs, though. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know -- sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I will describe everything for Windows 7 with a common USB Printer. Adapt the process where needed to your version. Network can usually be accessed the same way. Just use `//NetworkComputerName/SharedPrinterName` instead of //MyComputer/MyPrinter and skip steps 1.-6..

1. Go to *Start -> Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Devices and Printers*
2. Rightclick your printer select "Printer Properties"
3. Go to "Sharing" and check "Share this printer" and "Render print jobs on client computers"
4. Enter Share name: `MyPrinter` or something that you can remember and has no spaces.
5. Click OK to save your changes.
6. Go to *Start -> Computer* to check the name of your computer in the left lower corner (e.g `MyComputer`)
7. In Emacs evaluate `(setq printer-name "//MyComputer/MyPrinter")` or put it in your .emacs.el file
8. Done. You can print your files with `M-x print-buffer`

Answer (score 1):

add the following line to your emacs init file

```
(setq printer-name "//domain/printer-name")
```